# Using Test Roles for oAuth: 'Sorry, this feature isn't available right now'

Tags: facebook, authentication, testing, oauth, roles

We're having issues using Test Roles for oAuth.

Was working fine yesterday and nothing has changed our end.

I can however use oAuth with my actual Facebook account which is admin of the Facebook application.

With test roles, I get this error:

Sorry, this feature isn't available right now: An error occurred while processing this request. Please try again later.

Any ideas?

Cheers in advance!

Comment: I have updated the following bug
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/848036805237272/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been filed as https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/848036805237272/ and reported by other users.

Comment: I still have the issue today, the linked bug doesn't seem to concern the present issue